# Can't run my node js project in the Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I just clone my git to the Google cloud platform. And Im trying to deploy it.
As I type "gcloud app deploy" it says: 
[image]

And I have a file app.yaml and it looks like this:

```
# [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
```

I also tried changing the directory but cannot find the repo dir..

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the tool is unable to automatically detect the application's configuration file. Which could be caused by the now deprecated older generation of flexible apps configuration, using the `vm: true` statement. See cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading.

You should use the current flexible app configuration. I'd also suggest passing the actual app.yaml as argument to the deploying command, auto-detection might not always work as one expects.

Comment: hello sir Dan, i already changed the vm:true to env: flex in the app.yaml file and getting the same error. I also tried this "glcoud app deploy app.yaml"

Comment: That is odd. Can you give more information? What is the current directory content?

Comment: its "user@project-id:~$ gcloud app deploy app.yaml"

is there anything to change on the directory?